# NodeJS Buffer- read little endian buffer

Tags: node.js, buffer

I have a 256-bit long but written as a little endian:

```
<Buffer 21 a2 bc 03 6d 18 2f 11 f5 5a bd 5c b4 32 a2 7b 22 79 7e 53 9b cb 44 5b 0e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
```

How can I correctly print it as a hexadeciaml value?

```
buf.toString('hex')
```

`buk.toString('hex').split("").reverse().join(""))` gives `0x00000000000000e0b544bcb935e79722b72a234bc5dba55f11f281d630cb2a12` instead of `0x000000000000000e5b44cb9b537e79227ba232b45cbd5af5112f186d03bca221`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `match` instead of `split` to get an array of the two character groups.  Then you can reverse the array and join it.

```
buf.toString('hex').match(/.{2}/g).reverse().join("")
```

Comment: You can replace `/.{2}/` with shorter equivalent `/../`. Otherwise great answer.

Answer (score 3):

Actually `Buffer` objects support `reverse()` method, and it may be better to use it before converting to hex string,

```
buf.reverse().toString('hex')
```

Comment: works and is a lot faster than the other solution.